# HERE API GET query for static map marker

Tags: javascript, python, html, get, here-api

I have a tiny application with three files in the same dir:

- main.js
- python_script.py
- index.html

In main.js:

```
var platform = new H.service.Platform({
   'apikey': {my API key}

});

var defaultLayers = platform.createDefaultLayers();


var map = new H.Map(
document.getElementById('mapContainer'),
defaultLayers.vector.normal.map,
{
    zoom: 10,
    center: { lng: 17.0, lat: 51.0 }
});

window.addEventListener('resize', () => map.getViewPort().resize());
var behavior = new H.mapevents.Behavior(new H.mapevents.MapEvents(map));
var ui = H.ui.UI.createDefault(map, defaultLayers);
    ui.getControl('zoom').setDisabled(false)

function addWroclove() { 
        var markerWroclaw = new H.map.Marker({ lat: 51.0, lng: 17.0 }, { icon: icon });
        map.addObject(markerWroclaw);
    }
addWroclove();
```

In python_script.py:

```
import requests
URL_wro = "https://places.ls.hereapi.com/places/v1/browse?at=17.0%2C51.0&q=Wroclaw&apiKey=MY_API_KEY" 
wro = requests.get(URL_wro)
print(wro.text)
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pl">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no"/>
    <meta name="description" content=""/>
    <script src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-core.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-service.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-ui.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"  charset="utf-8" src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-mapevents.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" >window.ENV_VARIABLE = 'https://developer.here.com'</script>
    <script src='https://developer.here.com/javascript/src/iframeheight.js'></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-ui.css"/>
</head>
<body>
      <div class="map" id="mapContainer"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

My question is:
when I am trying to send GET query (in python_script.py) I am receiving data but from HERE server and not from map which is on my own remote server.
I mean - I want to have a GET's response from map in which i have declared my own marker (markerWroclaw).
How to make it works in a proper way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The browse endpoint will give you places from the HERE server. If you want to call locations that you add on the go, you will need to use the [Custom Location API](https://developer.here.com/documentation/custom-location/dev_guide/topics/what-is.html). While you add the location as a marker, you will also have to add it to your custom layer. From there you will be able to call and parse the layer of your custom locations.

As an example, below is the layer of custom POIs that I have uploaded to my map layer.

```
NAME    WKT
POINT1  POINT(13.402449957770752 52.505308544760155)
POINT2  POINT(13.408663845393365 52.499911895880146)
```

This can be uploaded using the call below

```
curl --request -i -X POST
    -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data"
    -F "zipfile=@my_folder/my_layer_content.zip"
    "https://fleet.ls.hereapi.com/2/layers/upload.json
    ?layer_id=POIS
    &apiKey={YOUR_API_KEY}"
```

or this [web tool](https://enterprise.here.com/).

Once uploaded, you can use this call to retrieve the points in the layer:

```
https://fleet.ls.hereapi.com/2/search/all.json?apikey={SameAPIKeyUsedToUpload}&layer_id=POIS
```

You can also perform a bunch of [search functions](https://developer.here.com/documentation/custom-location/dev_guide/topics/request-constructing.html) with this layer.

Comment: Thanks! This is really helpful. I created a WKT file and I uploaded it with curl call. Everything seems to work correctly. I just don't know how to make the points/markers to appear on the map which is on my own hosted website. Can you help me with this last step?

Comment: the function search/all also gives you geometries of all the points. you can call the layer in main.js and loop to add the marker on the map like you did in your code in the function addWroclove().

Comment: Thank you very much. It was quite complicated but I think I 've solved all the problems I had.